# Junit pattern when testing a method that checks boolean expressions

Tags: java, junit

I wonder what is the best way to test a method that only checks boolean expressions.

For example, I want to test this method :

```
boolean canDoSomething( Account account, User user )
    {
        return ( account.isAck() 
            && account.getEmail() != null
            && account.getName().equals( user.getProvider() );
    }
```

Do I have to write a junit method for each boolean combinations ? Like `whenNotAckThenDontDoSomething()`, `whenEmailIsNullThenDontDoSomethind()` ...

I think it's a little ugly so I wonder if there a better way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fully testing the method means testing each boolean combination within the expression. You may not always need this: test until you are confident that all possible failure options are covered.

You should test at least with each condition being false, while the others true, to verify that the return value is true only if all conditions are fulfilled. I.e.

- Test case 1: A false, B true, C true -> result should be false
- Test case 2: A true, B false, C true -> result should be false
- Test case 3: A true, B true, C false -> result should be false
- Test case 4: A true, B true, C true -> result should be true

Comment: Agreed. The more test cases (methods) you implement, the easier to find the problem. If we use with too many asserts in a single test case, then we end up with debugging the tests to see, why it failed.

Comment: Thanks that what I started to do, but I think it's a little too much for a simple method like that.

Comment: Finally I choose your solution because it will more improve my score on the Jenkins CI game :P

Answer (score 3):

As ever, test until fear turns into boredom. Maybe you don't need all eight possible combinations - perhaps try four: one with everything valid, and then make one condition false in each of the other tests.

Some folks would burn me at the stake for saying so, but you could probably express that as one positive test and one negative one:

```
public void testCanDoSomething_allValid() {
    assert.isTrue(foo.canDoSomething(new Account(true, "x@y.z", "Fred"),
                                     new User("Fred")));
}

public void testCanDoSomething_negative() {
    assert.isFalse(foo.canDoSomething(new Account(false, "x@y.z", "Fred"),
                                      new User("Fred")));
    assert.isFalse(foo.canDoSomething(new Account(true, null, "Fred"),
                                      new User("Fred")));
    assert.isFalse(foo.canDoSomething(new Account(true, "x@y.z", "Ginger"),
                                      new User("Fred")));
}
```

While there are definitely arguments for "only test one path in each test", I find that grouping very simple tests like this can *sometimes* lead to simpler test readability. Of course, when your tests start doing anything more complicated, you should break them out.

(There are also possibilities such as `user` or `account` being null, or the user name being null etc which you might want to consider.)

Comment: `test until fear turns into boredom` love that. About your suggestion, it brings me really closer to the boredom side :)))

Comment: My first comment targets the first line of your answer. Since you edit it, I think it is an elegant solution, not boring at all.